# Visual studio 2022 crashes when opening any project even by itself randomly

Tags: crash, visual-studio-2022

I recently had multiple issues with visual studio 2022.

1. Just in time tried constantly to debug online iis website when visual studio was closed. I fix it by removing problematic keys in the registry.
2. Code lens stopped working. To fix it, I tried to repair, uninstall then reinstall vs multiple times. Nothing was working.
3. It got worse (video linked) when I updated my bios. At this point, visual studio completly stop opening any project. It crashes when I try to open any project, or crashes all by itself when I open it without any project.

Do someone knows how to fix this?

[image: VS 2022 crashes record]

Comment: Maybe consider rolling-back the BIOS update (if possible) to check if that's the problem. It would be rather strange. But perhaps this could happen by coincidence if your memory timings or the disk controller were adversely affected? Do any other applications have strange new behaviors? It's possible that something is fundamentally busted on your system.

Comment: More things to try is check the application log in Event Viewer and/or see if VS generated a dump in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\CrashDumps`. Debug that with WinDbg, or a different version of VS. Oh yes, try different versions of VS and see if they are also broken.

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment. I found the crashdumps of devenv.exe and tried to debug it. Unfortunatly, I got an error => System.InvalidOperationException : 'The Undo operation must be performed on the thread where the corresponding context was set.'

Comment: @paddy I corrected the issue for the bios but I still have the same issue with VS 2022. Do you have any clue how I can solve it?

Comment: No. Otherwise I'd write an answer. Might be a general software issue, perhaps some corrupt data. If it were me, I'd start clearing out all my settings (_e.g._ removing `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio` and also `VisualStudio Services` and `VSCommon` in the same location. Anything VS-related. This is a _complete guess_, so do that at your own risk!! Other things to try is creating a new user on your system and see if that helps. Might confirm whether it's a user settings problem.